# Timephased Data in Azure Devops API

Tags: azure-devops

This is more of functional question. I am looking at the API and respective data which can provide me daily hours spent on Task/Bug/Feature/EPIC etc. by resources on a project. So far i have following queries which is giving me following:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime StateChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string WorkItemType { get; set; }
        public float? RemainingWork { get; set; }
        public float? OriginalEstimate { get; set; }
        public float? CompletedWork { get; set; }
```

Can someone suggest what should i refer to, so i can i have daily hours information for task/feature/epic etc.

Comment: Can you explain what the `daily hours` is?  I cannot find the existing field directly in work item. You can share the exact example(daily hours) in the work item.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  What i am looking for is some kind of information which i can utilize to identify how many hours resource has worked on work item. lets say Resource/Person has been working on issue for whole week starting from 12/12/2020-12/16/2020.  8 hours each day. is there a way to get 8 hours for each day ?

Comment: if this does not make sense, will some code help ? i am not doing anything fancy just wondering if i can get above information from Azure Devops

Comment: I can understand your requirements, but there is no such api to get this value directly, I shared a workaround in the answer, you can refer to it.  If it can give you some help, you can consider accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @e2eDev. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure devops does not focus on micromanaging and focus on low value metrics.

So, there is no API out of the box to get this value.

Azure devops doesn't track the time spent on a per day basis for a work item. It keeps track of the total time spent. If you want a per workitem per day value, you'll have to go through the iterations/workitem history and calculate the running difference. But this is not a convenient method.

Your requirement is a function similar to time reporting. I suggest that you could use the extension: [Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker)

Here is my example: In **Timetracker ->  TimeSheet**

[image]

You can add the time spent on a single work item each day. It will record and calculate the total time spent.

In Work item, you can also see the same information in the Time tab(After installing the extension).

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to use Work Item History to get the time, you could try the following Steps:

1. Add a custom field(e.g. DailyHour) for the work item type. You could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) for more detailed steps.

[image]

2. You could use the Rest API to get all Work item history. [Revisions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

You can use the script to compare the time field, and finally filter out the values that meet the conditions.

Here is My PowerShell Script Sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workItems/{WorkItemId}/revisions?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$startdate = (Get-Date 2020-11-21).toString("yyyy-M-dd")
$enddate   = (Get-Date 2020-12-19).toString("yyyy-M-dd")

$Totalhour = 0

ForEach( $day in $response.value.fields) 

{
   

   if($day.'System.ChangedDate' -ge $startdate -and $today -le $enddate)
   { 
     
     echo $day.'System.ChangedDate'
     echo $day.'System.ChangedBy'.displayName
     echo $day.'Custom.DailyHour'
     echo ''

     $Totalhour = $Totalhour + $day.'Custom.DailyHour'
   
   }

   echo $Totalhour

 
}
```

Result:

[image]

The Workflow: Any user updates his time in the daily hour after finishing the work, and then the work item history will record all the time.

In the above script, I filter according to a time period, you can judge according to each day, so as to get the total of each day

Comment: can you throw some light on WorkItem History please. wanted to check if i can get required information. before suggesting paid option to customer

Comment: @e2eDev Of course. I will share the sample with you. You could check my update. Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I guess we will take decision based on your answer and hopefully  customer will be satisfied. But just to put a perspective, we will give it revision a go first.